# menu item on mouseover

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface, drop-down-menu

I like this menu style where a rectangle (just an outline) moves horizontally based on mouse position. Can someone please guide me as to what should be the best way of doing this without using Flash? I am learning jQuery UI basics and would like to know if there is something within jQuery UI library which could help accomplishing this effect.

Comment: OK let me give you an example of kind of effect I am after:

Comment: http://www.aerovista.aero/ See how rectangle moves and resizes itself based on corresponding mouse position and menu item

Comment: http://www.aerovista.aero/ I got inspiration from this Nav menu